# Equivalent elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have this quartic which I want to change into a Weierstrass elliptic curve :

$$v^2 = (p^4 - 2p^3 + 5p^2 + 8p + 4)$$

and I found a different elliptic curve to the one in the book and was told that they are the same by some change of variable.

I found: $y^2=x^3-(121/3)x-1690/27$.

Book : $y^2 = x^3-3267x+45630$

How is that even possible. I tried scaling through with a factor of 81 (by looking at the coefficient of $x$), but it did not help. Can someone help me drop few hints?

In the book :
[image]

My calculation by using Maple :

[image]

I noticed and tried playing around with the change of variable because they look almost the same with a difference in the constant term with no luck. Can someone help me indicate why these are different yet the same. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct - the curves are not the same, as shown in this [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ywko9npfa8). Can you post the original question? If you show us how you got to your answer, other people might be able to find the correct answer.

Comment: Yes I will edit my question.  Thank you

Comment: Let $P(x) = x^3-3627 x + 45630$. Then $9^{-3}P(9x) = ?$ @TobyMak

Comment: Did you try replacing $x$ with $cx$  and $y$ with $by$ for some $b,c$?

Comment: @reuns It kind of almost worked but the x coefficient is different. Your suggestion gave : X^3-403/9X+1690/27

Comment: @reuns. Owh sorry made a silly mistake in my calculation. I got this : X^3 - 121/3*X + 1690/27. coefficients are the same but the coefficients of 1690/27 should be a negative.

Comment: Is this sign really a problem ?

Comment: @reuns. correct me if Im wrong. Does this means that the change of variable from "book" curve to "my" curve is : x=9X and y=9^{-3}Y ?

Comment: I did some calculation using the change of variables. It seems like the x change of variables differ by "-9" and y change of variables differ by 3^3.